# How to send a request using JQuery Ajax when submitting a form without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jsp, request

I have this form here that requires the user to enter a value.

```
<form id="result" name="result" action="/HelloStruts2/views/register.action" method="post">
    <label>UserName</label>
    <input type="text" name="userBean.username" value="" id="result_userBean_username"/>
    <input type="submit" id="registerSubmit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

and this is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#registerSubmit').live('click',function(){
         alert("XD");
         $.ajax({
             //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
             url: "register.action", 
             //GET method is used
             type: "POST",
             //pass the data           
             //Do not cache the page
             cache: false,
             //success
             success: function (html) {              
                 //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                $('#result').html(html);       
             }       
         });
     })
})
```

The form is being validated successfully when I submit the form the thing is instead of sending a request, the whole page is being reloaded or refresh, how do I prevent this from happening?

**UPDATE**
I have updated my script with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#result').on('submit',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
             url: "register.action", 
             //GET method is used
             type: "POST",     
             //Do not cache the page
             cache: false,
             //success
             success: function (html) {              
                $('#content').html(html);       
             }       
         });
     })
})
```

but when I click the button the second time, the page is reloading instead of sending a request

Comment: There is more than one way to submit a form, so please don't bind to a button that may not actually be used to submit it.

Comment: Does #result exist inside #content?

Comment: Does the form with id result exists inside of whatever element has the id content?

Comment: i thought so, see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop it from being submitted (page reloading) use `preventDefault();`

However, there is more than one way to submit a form, so please don't bind to a button that may not actually be used to submit it. In your example if I press enter in the text field a submit would be triggered on the the form; Any events bound to a submit button would not be caught and important script not executed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#result').live('submit',function(e){ // e is the event
           e.preventDefault(); // stop the event's default action
           alert("XD");
           ...
```

**Aside:**

`live()` is depreciated for very good reasons. Use `on()`

If the form already exists (by the time that JS is executed) simply replace `live()`

```
$('#result').on('submit', function...
```

or if it's generated dynamically you have to bind to something that already exists, which #result will end up being inside of

```
$(document).on('submit', '#result', function()...
```

**EDIT**

Given the updated code and new problem I suspect the form with id result exists inside of whatever element has the id content in which case on() needs fixing to an element that already exists, as I noted previously. In this instance, `#content` is the appropriate element.

```
$('#content').on('submit', '#result', function()...
```

Comment: why did you prefer to use submit rather than onclick?

Comment: The action is bound to the form not the button. Using on 'click' would mean when the user clicks **anywhere** in the form it is submitted.

Comment: In your example if I press enter in the text field a submit would be triggered on the the form; Any events bound to a submit button would not be executed.

Comment: I did your suggestions, but if I clicked the button two times the whole page reloads. but on the first submission it is working.

Comment: You should be able to click the button as many times as you like without it triggering a real submit, unless you're reloading it dynamically and have replaced live() with on() but without the context of document, but I don't know exactly what your code looks like after the modifications so hard to debug.

Comment: no it would destroy the question but you could add it to the question

Comment: I tried it again and on the second press or submit it is reloading, what I am trying to do is that replace the #result div with the incoming html. how would I do that?

Comment: Also the incoming html also contains the same form, same ids,form name and etc.

Comment: When you replace that HTML all your bound events are lost, which is why you need to use on() in the way that live() would function by giving it context of something that isn't changed `$('#content').on('submit', '#result', function()...` otherwise it won't bind to the new form with id result.

Comment: I tried it already but it is still refreshing on the second click, anyways I'll just ask that in a different question.

Comment: have you tried that? The code you posted in your edit shows you using on in a way that it wouldn't bind to reloaded HTML.

Comment: Yes I did try it.but it is still keep on reloading on the second press. I even checked the console for errors but nada.

Comment: OK if you say so but it's pretty clear you're losing the bound event when you reload the form so I'm not convinced.

Comment: are there alternatives with live? I feel like the on is not being bound on the form. one last thing, how do you get a fragment of the incoming html from the success? maybe that's causing the error since I am retrieving the whole page.

Comment: You can but you wouldn't take a fragment, you'd send only the bit you wanted. Can you post the line with the on() in it please?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kyyua/ btw how can I get only a fragment of the html that has been responded for me?

Comment: Ok if you really want to do it that way turn it into a dom object, find that element, get its contents `$('#result').html($(html).find('#result').html());`

Comment: tried it already, it doesnt reload on the second trigger, but it stopped showing content of the incoming html

Answer (score 1):

Add an event variable that you can work with "e"

```
$('#registerSubmit').live('click',function(e){
```

and add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This will prevent the page from reloading. So you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#registerSubmit').live('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("XD");
         $.ajax({
             //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
             url: "register.action", 
             //GET method is used
             type: "POST",
             //pass the data           
             //Do not cache the page
             cache: false,
             //success
             success: function (html) {              
                 //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                $('#result').html(html);       
             }       
         });
     })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#registerSubmit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Use the jQuery .click function and put event.preventDefault() to stop from going to the form action page.